# npm package contains more than one file - how to umport these

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've a npm package with the following three files in the dist folder (generated by webpack):

[image]

Inside the package.json file I've declated the `sample.js` file as the main one: `"main": "dist/sample.js",`.

Now I wan't to use this package in another project. Did I need to import all three files? Or should all work fine with one import like `import aFunction from 'package-name'`?

Comment: Probably best to export everything from your main file. So in sample import & re-export any functions you want public from the other files.

Comment: It depends on the content

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any other weird dependencies, and `sample.js` is actually the entrypoint of the library (i.e. either you do everything inside it, or you make all the needed exports from it), it should work fine just as you wrote, i.e. `import aFunction from 'package-name'`.

Btw, is `sample.js` minified? As far as I remember, starting with Webpack v4 it does the minification automatically for production builds. But you might still want to doublecheck (read [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification) for more info).